# Index of nth pattern match in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a program where I'm attempting to find the index of the nth occurrence of the letter "e". I guessed something like this...

```
def findE(line: String, ignore: Int) : Int = {
    val pattern = "e".r
    val index = line.indexOf(pattern(ignore+1))
    index
}
```

where

```
ignore+1
```

is the desired group, but the syntax isn't valid. Was wondering if anyone knew how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use standard combinators if I were you.

```
> "abcdeabcdeabcde".zipWithIndex.collect {
    case ('e', index) => index
  }
res1: collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(4, 9, 14)
```

Just take whatever is at index 5, if it exists, and that's your answer.